# 2 Arrays of data that refill on a loop, how to turn data to insert query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-insert, alter-table

I have 2 Arrays I've read from a text file, one is the Field name the other the field data.

```
array (size=12) //name $columns
  0 => string 'Name' (length=4)
  1 => string 'Telephone' (length=9)
  2 => string 'Email' (length=5)
  3 => string 'selling' (length=7)
  4 => string 'buying' (length=6)
  5 => string 'textarea' (length=8)
  6 => string 'Country' (length=7)
  7 => string 'IP' (length=2)
  8 => string 'Referer' (length=7)
  9 => string 'Server Time' (length=11)
  10 => string 'Browser' (length=7)
  11 => string 'User Agent' (length=10)

array (size=12) //name $values
  0 => string ' john smith' (length=12)
  1 => string ' 01234 567 897' (length=14)
  2 => string ' test@test.com' (length=32)
  3 => string ' Euros and US$' (length=14)
  4 => string ' Euros and US$' (length=14)
  5 => string ' Notes bur selling $ traveller cheques' (length=38)
  6 => string ' UNITED KINGDOM' (length=15)
  7 => string ' 11.222.33.44' (length=14)
  8 => string ' http//www.anaddress.html' (length=48)
  9 => string ' 2011-12-09 07' (length=14)
  10 => string ' Firefox' (length=8)
  11 => string ' Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111103 Firefox/3.6.24' (length=95)
```

Now I want to insert these into a table, now problem 1) is construction the mysql query. problem 2) Is i'm sure some of these text files i'm looping through some of the columns will be different, how can i get it to if the column doesn't exist to create it and carry on.

I'm a relative noob, with a little coding background, but this is beating me.

I'm using php  5.4.12 and a local host wamp server.

Please help, so i can learn.

Comment: check your filed name array contains invalid names. that need to be corrected first.. update your table structure

Comment: When you say that "the columns will be different" and "if the column doesn't exist to create it and carry on", do you mean that these 12 field names are fixed and unchanging, but it's possible that some of the values in the `$values` array are blank?

Comment: This kinda sounds like a homework assignment. Regarding the columns being different or not exist, you should add some basic validation into your script.  Ie. if you it's an email field make sure an email is being added into it (or blank if not exist).  If it's money, make sure it's valid money values being put in, if IP make sure it fits the pattern, etc.  If it checks out great, insert the record.  If it doesn't then have it spit it out and tell you what line failed and what failed about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that all the $columns var exists in your table.
If not you can compare them first by using `DESCRIBE table` and then parsing to check if the column exists or not.

```
if ( sizeof($columns) != sizeof($values) ) die() ;

$col_table = Array() ;
    $sql = ' describe `table` ' ;
    $rq = ... ; // Do your request
    while ( $d = mysql_fetch_assoc($rq) )
    {
        $col_table[] = $d['Field'] ;
    }
    foreach ( $columns as $index => $colname )
    {
        if ( ! in_array($colname,$col_table) )
        {
            // There is a problem here... Your colname doesn't exists, you need to skip the entry $index for cols and vals
            unset($columns[$index]) ;
            unset($values[$index]) ;
        }
    }
```

And after that,

```
    if ( sizeof($columns) == sizeof($values) )
    {
        $sql = ' insert into table (`'.implode('`,`',$columns).'`) values (' ;
            $temp = Array() ;
            foreach ( $values as $val ) $temp[] = '"'.mysql_escape_string($val).'"' ;
            $sql .= implode(', ',$temp) ;
        $sql .= ')' ;
    }
```